# How to place button under content from database

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, instagram

I have an issue with css i have this content generated from database, so I expect on the online version, there would be so much content generated, so in order to make the application work faster and better and also to prevent the browser from crashing due to so many data loaded i limit the result to 8, then i put an add more button, but i want this add more button to stay under the content generated and even if i delete a product with ajax it should auto move up this is the current state of the button [image: the button moves on top which i know is caused by position:absolute] now how do i go about placing it under my page like a footer but not sticky cause if i use `bottom:0` it places but if content is less than 8 generated content from database, the button stays far from the main content. Something more of like instagram load more button, the button stays at the bottom of the page. this is my button code

```
  <button class="btn" id="zuan" style="background: #3897f0!important; position: absolute;text-align: center;margin-left:-45%;outline:none!important;  margin-bottom:25px;  border: 0px!important;     color: #fff!important;     padding: 12px 24px!important;border-radius:0px;">LOAD MORE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers you can use `position: sticky` to stick when it reaches the top (or bottom).

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.

Read more in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
.sticky-button {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 500px; height: 3000px; background: #ffffcc; padding: 20px'>
  <div style='width: 500px; height: 2000px; background: #eeffff; padding: 20px'>
    Page content
  </div>
  <button class='sticky-button'>Load more...</button>
</div>
```

Browsers supporting ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)):

[image]

Unfortunately, there isn't a clear spec for this one - the feature is just landed on Webkit and there are some known issues. But for buttons it works well

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way around it this is the solution. This will position even footer below the page even if the page content is short.

```
<button class="btn" id="zuan">LOAD MORE</button>
<br/>
<style>


html {
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 6rem;
min-height: 100%;
}   


#zuan{
position: absolute;
background-color: #3897f0;
outline:none!important;
border: 0px!important;    
color: #fff!important;
border-radius:0px;
padding: 12px 24px!important;
margin-left:-45%;
bottom: -100;
padding: 1rem;
text-align: center; 
margin-bottom:30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: So you button needs to be placed right after content but not  keeping sticky over it when scrolling up?